# Exoplayer - Plays same audio over and over on reopening the activity

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, exoplayer2.x

I'm creating an exoplayer instance and adding a stream URL as progressive media source, preparing the player and playing the audio. When I go back to previous activity and open the player activity again, another instance of player is running the same audio (Two instances playing same audio simultaneously). Also I have a mute button. It works as expected when I open the activity for the first time. On reopening the activity, the mute button mutes only the ExoPlayer instance of the current activity

I tried Moving the ExoPlayer code to another class and calling them with public functions, but didn't work

```
val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, packageName))
val newMediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse("STREAM URL"));
val exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this);
exoPlayer.prepare((newMediaSource));
exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true;

muteButton.setOnClickListener {
    if(muteButton.tag == "muted")
    {
        exoPlayer.volume = 1f;
        muteButton.tag = "unmuted";
    }
    else
    {
        exoPlayer.volume = 0f;
        muteButton.tag = "muted";
    }
}
```

I want the same ExoPlayer to run on reopening the activity and also mute that particular instance

Comment: Override `onBackPressed()` and call `finish()` inside it. Don't even think you have to call `finish()`.

Comment: Tried. Didn't work. Still the audio is playing. Also forgot to mention that I need the audio to play in the background. So I cannot stop the player onBackPressed()

Comment: If you finish the activity, there should be not reference to exoplayer, unless you are storing exoplayer in memory. Did you try releasing exoplayer?

Comment: Yes. But releasing the player doesn't help me because I want the audio to play in the background too

Comment: So are you runing exoplayer in a service then? You did not mention that in the question. You should check in your Activity's `onCreate` if the service is running, if it is you should first stop it and then start it again passing the new file.

Comment: I am not running exoplayer in a service. Running it as a service will help me solve the issue I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195917/discussion-between-prasanna-kumar-and-hb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using shared preference to save the service's state. So whenever the service is started, the boolean in shared preference is set to true. So I can start the service only when the boolean is false. Also I am using Broadcast receiver in both activity and service to exchange messages.